Osm2pgsql does nothing
When I try to use osm2pgsql, it returns after a second without any import or error message.
What may be wrong?
C:\osm2pgsql>C:\osm2pgsql\osm2pgsql.exe --database=postgres --host=ubuntu.forplan.local --user=fds --password --schema=osm_2024_06_16 --slim --cache 30000 --prefix=osm --output=flex --style C:\osm2pgsql\flex-config\flex_fds.lua "C:\Users\Kai\Downloads\luxembourg-latest.osm.pbf"
Password:

2024-06-17 13:05:21  osm2pgsql version 1.11.0
2024-06-17 13:05:21  Database version: 14.5 (Ubuntu 14.5-0ubuntu0.22.04.1)
2024-06-17 13:05:21  PostGIS version: 3.2

C:\osm2pgsql>

I tried to adjust a configuration I used two years ago. At that time I had to manually extract the file "epsg" from a proj download - maybe there is a similar problem this time? But I tried removing the projection from the lua file and got the same result.
This is flex_fds.lua:
-- einfache Konfiguration für osm2pgsql-Flex-mode
-- 2024-06-17 Kai Borgolte (FORPLAN DR. SCHMIEDEL)

local tables = {}
tables.point = osm2pgsql.define_node_table('osm_point', {
    {column = 'tags', type = 'jsonb'},
    {column = 'geom', type = 'point', projection = 25832, not_null = true},
}, { schema = 'osm_2024_06_16' })
tables.line = osm2pgsql.define_way_table('osm_line', {
    {column = 'tags', type = 'jsonb'},
    {column = 'nodes', sql_type = 'bigint[]'},
    {column = 'geom', type = 'linestring', projection = 25832, not_null = true},
}, { schema = 'osm_2024_06_16' })
tables.polygon = osm2pgsql.define_area_table('osm_polygon', {
    {column = 'tags', type = 'jsonb'},
    {column = 'nodes', sql_type = 'bigint[]'},
    {column = 'geom', type = 'multipolygon', projection = 25832, not_null = true},
}, { schema = 'osm_2024_06_16' })

-- Helper function to remove some of the tags we usually are not interested in.
-- Returns true if there are no tags left.
function clean_tags(tags)
    tags.odbl = nil
    tags.created_by = nil
    tags.source = nil
    tags['source:ref'] = nil

    return next(tags) == nil
end

-- Helper function that looks at the tags and decides if this is possibly
-- an area.
function has_area_tags(tags)
    if tags.area == 'yes' then
        return true
    end
    if tags.area == 'no' then
        return false
    end

    return tags['abandoned:aeroway']
        or tags['abandoned:amenity']
        or tags['abandoned:building']
        or tags['abandoned:landuse']
        or tags['abandoned:power']
        or tags.aeroway
        or tags.amenity
        or tags['area:highway']
        or tags.building
        or tags['building:part']
        or tags.harbour
        or tags.historic
        or tags.landuse
        or tags.leisure
        or tags.man_made
        or tags.military
        or tags.natural
        or tags.office
        or tags.place
        or tags.power
        or tags.public_transport
        or tags.shop
        or tags.sport
        or tags.tourism
        or tags.water
        or tags.waterway
        or tags.wetland
end

function osm2pgsql.process_node(object)
    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end
    tables.point:insert({
        tags = object.tags,
        geom = object:as_point()
    })
end

function osm2pgsql.process_way(object)
    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end
    if object.is_closed and has_area_tags(object.tags) then
        tables.polygon:insert({
            nodes = '{' .. table.concat(object.nodes, ',') .. '}',
            tags = object.tags,
            geom = object:as_multipolygon()
        })
    else
        tables.line:insert({
            nodes = '{' .. table.concat(object.nodes, ',') .. '}',
            tags = object.tags,
            geom = object:as_linestring()
        })
    end
end

function osm2pgsql.process_relation(object)
    if clean_tags(object.tags) then
        return
    end

    -- Store multipolygons and boundaries as polygons
    if object.tags.type == 'multipolygon' or
       object.tags.type == 'boundary' then
         tables.polygon:insert({
            tags = object.tags,
            geom = object.as_multipolygon()
        })
    end
end


I now tried osm2pgsql version 1.10.0, which works. So there seems to be a bug in the binaries for 1.11.0.
